# Run html2text using parallel while deleting the input

Tags: python, html, linux, terminal, parallel-processing

I was able to use parallel on html2text via this code

```
find . -type f -name \*html > FLIST
parallel --a FLIST -j 1000 'html2text {} > {.}.txt'
```

Now, how can I delete each `.html` input file once it was converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
find . -type f -name \*html > FLIST
parallel --a FLIST -j 1000 'html2text {} > {.}.txt; rm {}'
```